# laravel cashier publish payment confirmation page

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-cashier

I'm testing Laravel Cashier for accepting Stripe payments. Everything is working, but still looks bad. I see in the docs that there is a 'cashier.payments' page that can be published so we can modify it to match our page. I'd love to use that, but I can't see how to use it. There's no existing route and without the code, I wouldn't know how to create one (it requires some parameters).

I tried `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cashier-payment"` (based on the instructions for publishing the billing-portal), but the response was 'No publishable resources for tag'.

I've looked through the 'vendor/stripe' folder, but can't see anything like 'cashier/payments' that would help.

Has it been removed? Or does anyone know how to activate it?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

run `php artisan vendor:publish`

and then select tag:

```
php artisan vendor:publish cashier-views
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on another project now, but this is still a problem. I'll test it and confirm that it works as soon as I have time.

Comment: anytime my solution will still be here